# Exporting Serialized ACF Field Groups with Import Export Suite for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, serialization, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to export my products with WP All Export Pro plugin. I also used the ACF plugin to show details like specifications on my products. However, when exporting products, it exports serialized. I also tried exporting using the [Import Export Suite for WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce/) and ended up with the same result.

Serialized example data below

> a:4:{s:12:"pa_waist-pad";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:12:"pa_waist-pad";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:19:"pa_d-ring-placement";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:19:"pa_d-ring-placement";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:17:"pa_leg-connection";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:17:"pa_leg-connection";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:2;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:7:"pa_size";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_size";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:3;s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}

I deserialized them with the code below.

```
function data_deserialize_csv($value)
{
$output = '';
$data = unserialize($value); 
print_r($data);$data = reset($data);
return $data['specs_product'];
```

}

The output of the above code is as follows

```
Array


[header] => 

[caption] => 

[body] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => Attachment Points: 




                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [c] =>  1 dorsal D-ring
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => Weight:  

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 3.7 lbs. (1.7 kg)
```

I just need values like weight in this output. For example;

> Weight:130kg,Height:130cm,Attachment Points:1 dorsal D-ring

UPDATE 1

When I use the code below

```
function data_deserialize_csv($value)
{
$data = unserialize($value); 
unset ($value);
return implode( ',', $data );   
print_r ($data);
```

It gives the following output

> Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array

Update 2

When I use the code below

```
function data_deserialize_csv($valuess)
{
$data = unserialize($valuess);
foreach ($data as $key => $data) {
$output= $key." =>".$data.","; }
unset($value);
return $output;
```

}

It gives the following output

> pa_leg-connection =>Array,

Comment: Have you tried this [WooCommerce product export plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce)?

Comment: Yes i tried it. It doesn't export ACF fields as unserialized.

Comment: You can use this filter `wt_iew_alter_export_data` to alter the export data. Just share the value in the database as it is, and the key name, making the snippet really simple.

Comment: WooCommerce product export plugin is not compatible with ACF. The function you mentioned processes static values.

Comment: `apply_filters( 'wt_batch_product_export_row_data', $row, $product );` Can use this for dynamic values

Comment: It outputs as serialized.

Comment: Please share the metakey and value exported, it can be altered to scalar data as mentioned using the above filter.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Updated the answer, with sample meta key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet with the [Import Export Suite for WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce/) to export the product data in a custom format.

```
add_filter('wt_batch_product_export_row_data', 'wt_batch_product_export_row_data_acf', 10, 2);

function wt_batch_product_export_row_data_acf($row, $product) {

    if (isset($row['meta:specs_product']) && !empty($row['meta:specs_product'])) {
        $acf_data = json_decode($row['meta:specs_product']);
        if (!empty($acf_data)) {
            $acf_string = '';
            $acf_string .= "Weight:" . $acf_data->b[1][1]->c;
            $acf_string .= ', ';
            $acf_string .= "ANSI Weight Capacity:" . $acf_data->b[2][1]->c;
            $row['meta:specs_product'] = $acf_string;
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Change the key as per your requirements.

[image]

Comment: {"acftf":{"v":"1.3.14"},"p":{"o":{"uh":0}},"c":[{"p":""},{"p":""}],"h":[{"c":""},{"c":""}],"b":[[{"c":"Attachment Points: \n\n\n\n"},{"c":" 1 dorsal D-ring"}],[{"c":"Weight:  \n"},{"c":"3.7 lbs. (1.7 kg)"}],[{"c":"ANSI Weight Capacity:  \n"},{"c":"130-310 lbs. (59-141 kg)\n"}],[{"c":"OSHA Weight Capacity:  \n"},{"c":"Up to 420 lbs. (191 kg)"}],[{"c":"ANSI Standards:  \n"},{"c":"Z359.11-2014"}],[{"c":"OSHA Standards:"},{"c":"1926.502, 1910.140"}]]}

Comment: I need Weight: 3.7lbs, ANSI Weight Capacity: 130-310 lbs

Comment: it returns critical error on web site

Comment: @bekoyzc Corrected the braces. Please use the updated code

Comment: I double checked. Can you check please?

Comment: @bekoyzc Have you replaced with the latest update? Yes, I tested now and it works.

Comment: Yep. Output: {"acftf":{"v":"1.3.14"},"p":{"o":{"uh":0}},"c":[{"p":""},{"p":""}],"h":[{"c":""},{"c":""}],"b":[[{"c":"Attachment Points: \n\n\n\n"},{"c":" 1 dorsal D-ring"}],[{"c":"Weight:  \n"},{"c":"3.7 lbs. (1.7 kg)"}],[{"c":"ANSI Weight Capacity:  \n"},{"c":"130-310 lbs. (59-141 kg)\n"}],[{"c":"OSHA Weight Capacity:  \n"},{"c":"Up to 420 lbs. (191 kg)"}],[{"c":"ANSI Standards:  \n"},{"c":"Z359.11-2014"}],[{"c":"OSHA Standards:"},{"c":"1926.502, 1910.140"}]]}

Comment: meta:specs_product

Comment: Updated the snippet for meta key "meta:specs_product". Please make sure meta key is meta:specs_product instead of meta:_specs_product

Comment: is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Underscore is the difference

Comment: Everything is the same no change

Comment: I tried both meta information

Comment: Can u share the export sample CSV. Make sure the [plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce/) is active and on the step 4 corresponding meta column is checked for export.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244388/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-bekoyzc).